# How can I display an image on an imageview from the server on an asynctask onPostExecute?

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap, android-asynctask

I have a table for articles in my mysql, every article has an image.

```
**article_id**    **article_image**
00001         display/Article1image.png
00002         display/Article2image.jpg
00003         display/Article3image.jpg
00004         display/Article4image.png
```

Let's suppose that I'm printing all the article information on a linearlayout with a different view like the article_content, article_writer, date_published, and so on.., and I want to display the article_image on a programmatically created ImageView

Suppose that `"www.sampleweb.com/"+_jsonObject.optString("article_image").toString()' is the full link of the image from the server.

Here is my full code, how can I create the imageview with the content of the above url for the image?

```
@Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //headlinehead.setText(result);
        try{
            JSONObject jsonRootObj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObj.optJSONArray("Data");
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            //code for headline
            this.headlinehead.setText(jsonObject.optString("title").toString());
            this.shortdesc.setText(jsonObject.optString("shortdesc").toString());
            this.headlinesender.setText(jsonObject.optString("penname").toString());
            this.img.setTag(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
            //code for headline
            for (int p = 1; p < jsonArray.length(); p++){
                JSONObject _jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(p);
                LinearLayout conteach = new LinearLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                conteach.setLayoutParams(lp);
                conteach.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                TextView art_title = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                art_title.setText(_jsonObject.optString("title").toString());
                art_title.setTextSize(20);
                art_title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(350,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView art_shortdesc = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                art_shortdesc.setText(_jsonObject.optString("shortdesc").toString());
                art_shortdesc.setTextSize(14);
                art_shortdesc.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                art_shortdesc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(350,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView art_sender = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                art_sender.setText("Written by: " + _jsonObject.optString("sender").toString());
                art_sender.setTextSize(14);
                art_sender.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(350,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                art_sender.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 15);


                conteach.addView(art_title);
                conteach.addView(art_shortdesc);
                conteach.addView(art_sender);
                conteach.setTag(_jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                conteach.setClickable(true);
                conteach.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SpecificArticleFragment spcf = new SpecificArticleFragment();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("art_id", v.getTag().toString());
                        spcf.setArguments(args);

                        FragmentManager ft = getFragmentManager();
                        ft.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, spcf).commit();
                    }
                 });                
                this.llist.addView(conteach);

            }
            this.pbColBul.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        } catch(JSONException e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use one of many existing libraries. Take a look at these two: Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/, and Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide/. Otherwise you will have to download and possibly cache the images yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Create your ImageView programmatically like you did with the Textview. Load the url into it using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It does a great job
and provides you with some useful methods along side with a fading-in affect when image is finished loading out of the box.
As for JSON parsing, I recommend using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) with [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) client. It's much easier than your implementation. Plus, Retrofit can make API calls in background, so, drop the `AsyncTask`.